# I don't know how to remove a strange symbol that appears when I enter "\"

Tags: texmaker

My problem appears when a I want to insert some math symbol , for example , if I want to write \alpha (or any other) appears symbols between "\" and "alpha",I mean to somemethings as  \♠alpha or \©alpha , this does not always happen[image] but is happen on averege 1 out of 40 times , It's so weird because only happen me in "Texmaker"

((I want to apologize, English is not my native language, thanks ))

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest using LaTeX in a monospaced (typewriter) font because it is somewhat a programming language.

Comment: that it only happens in one editor is to be expected, the issue will not be related to latex itself but just to the keybindings you have in that editor. I don't have texmaker myself so I can't help but see what keyboard shortcuts and  bindings are enabled

Comment: This is maybe some bugs of your TeXmaker. You should report it to the TeXmaker developers.